# When moving pages, you should be anchored to the top of the next page, some pages you are anchored to the bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I move to another page I get anchored to the bottom of the page. Is there any way I can fix this ?

How can I do it with React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML standard's #scroll-to-the-fragment-identifier section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#scroll-to-the-fragment-identifier) specifies the display behavior. The standard is very specific in terms of the decision tree and there are several options to consider, but MDN's [`<a>`: The Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) illustrates a possible easy solution:

> You can use href="#top" or the empty fragment (href="#") to link to
> the top of the current page

As for React, that's a Javascript framework and Javascript can dynamically write HTML or control the UI.